# While loop/ if else loop to read and validate IP address

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

The below program is supposed to read and validate an IP address keyed in by the user. Validations of IP works fine . What I need is figuring out the setup of the condition(while/if&else) that will prompt the user to re-enter IP in case of keying in invalid IP address?

```
        echo "Enter an IP address:"
          read IP_ADDRESS
   


    # Check if the format looks right 
    if echo "$IP_ADDRESS" | egrep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
    then
  

     #check that each octect is less than or equal to 255:
     VALID_IP_ADDRESS="$(echo $IP_ADDRESS | awk -F'.' '$1 <=255 && $2 <= 255 && $3 <= 
     25&&  $4 <= 255')" 
     
    
    ## Here is the Pseudo code of  what I am trying to achieve 
    # If the IP address is not VALID_IP_ADDRESS prompt the user to re-enter IP
    #Pseudo Code not actaul
    while [[ ! VALID_IP_ADDRESS]] do 
    read -p "Not an IP. Re-enter: " IP_ADDRESS
     done
     # Another way to I tried 
     if  $VALID_IP_ADDRESS; then
    
     echo "You have alright IP address!"
     else
    read -p "Not an IP. Re-enter: " IP_ADDRESS
    fi
```

Comment: Why bother reinvetng the wheel? Use `ipcalc`. This tool returns 0 on success and 1 on failure. Thus `ipcalc -s -c <ip>` will return 0 if ip is valid and 1 if invalid. As a side note: there are two `if`'s but only one `fi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
is_valid() {
    IP_ADDRESS="$1"
    # Check if the format looks right_ (Added the two extra meta characters for better results)
    echo "$IP_ADDRESS" | egrep -qE '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$' || return 1
    #check that each octet is less than or equal to 255:
    echo $IP_ADDRESS | awk -F'.' '$1 <=255 && $2 <= 255 && $3 <=255 && $4 <= 255 {print "Y" } ' | grep -q Y || return 1
    return 0
}

read -p "Enter a valid IP: " IP_ADDRESS
while ! is_valid "$IP_ADDRESS"
do
    read -p "Not an IP. Re-enter: " IP_ADDRESS
done
echo "Success.  You entered a valid IP address of $IP_ADDRESS"
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response- Thanks for the very clear/intuitive  answer you shared . Take a bow. @John1024

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `done` to close `while [[ ! VALID_IP_ADDRESS]] do`. Try adding that and see if your current solution works. You're also not rechecking the re-entered ip in your loop.

Comment: I did done already , It didnt work

Comment: 'fi' is missing for one of the 'if' block

Comment: You're also not rechecking the ip in the loop where you re-enter it.

Comment: @Tobi Hahn that is a good point, I am more of questioning the logic of the code ,,, what you pointed out is something that I will fix